# Make Enum (with associated type) Codable, successfully

Tags: swift, codable

I'm having trouble getting my Codable type to properly decode.  I have read a few tutorials on making `Codable` enums with associated types.  I've searched for typos, name mismatches, or whatever but I can't spot anything wrong with this.  And yet whenever I try to decode on of these structs (a Layer.. this defines an "Attribute" on a layer in an extension.. but all the other predefined parts of Layer are being properly en/de-coded), I hit a "key not found" exception in the `decode(from decoder:)` method.

```
extension Layer {

    struct Attribute: Codable {

        enum Value: Codable {

            case pulse(Double)
            case flash(Double)
            case draw(Double)

            private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case pulse, flash, draw
            }

            func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

                var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

                switch self {
                case .pulse(let value):
                    try container.encode(value, forKey: .pulse)
                case .flash(let value):
                    try container.encode(value, forKey: .flash)
                case .draw(let value):
                    try container.encode(value, forKey: .draw)
                }
            }

            init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

                let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

                do {
                    let value = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .pulse)
                    self = .pulse(value)
                } catch (let error) {
                    print(error)
                }

                do {
                    let value = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .draw)
                    self = .draw(value)
                } catch (let error) {
                    print(error)
                }

                do {
                    let value = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .flash)
                    self = .flash(value)
                } catch (let error) {
                    print(error)
                }

                self = .draw(0.0)
            }


        }

        var value: Value

        init(value: Value) {
            self.value = value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should first check whether a key exists in the decoder's container or not, before decoding it. Currently, you are doing this:

```
do {
    let value = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .pulse)
    self = .pulse(value)
} catch (let error) {
    print(error)
}

do {
    let value = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .draw)
    self = .draw(value)
} catch (let error) {
    print(error)
}

do {
    let value = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .flash)
    self = .flash(value)
} catch (let error) {
    print(error)
}
```

There is no way that the decoder container is going to have all three keys in there, isn't it?

So, check before decoding:

```
if values.contains(.pulse) {
    do {
        let value = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .pulse)
        self = .pulse(value)
        return // remember to return here, so you don't set self back to .draw(0.0) again!
    } catch (let error) {
        print(error)
    }
} else if values.contains(.draw) {
    do {
        let value = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .draw)
        self = .draw(value)
        return
    } catch (let error) {
        print(error)
    }
} else if values.contains(.flash) {
    do {
        let value = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .flash)
        self = .flash(value)
        return
    } catch (let error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah the main thing was that i wasn't returning after `self = ...` i assumed Swift implicitly returns after initialization but i was wrong.  without the returns my original code works though I agree with your improvements.  I also didn't know that `values.decode` returned a normal collection upon which you could do simple operations like `.contains`